# Usage of @Autowired on constructor

Tags: java, spring

What is the benifit of using @Autowired on constructor as below,

```
@Autowired
public MyClass(A a){
}
```

Comment: As opposed to *what*? What is the context here?

Comment: @Autowired is used for the constructor. In the background the SpringFramework will search the repo for all instances of type "A" if found the object will be instantiated else an error will be thrown

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This way bean `A` will be injected into the constructor. It is cleaner because you kind of declare the dependencies of the bean, because it can't be instantiated without supplying `A`. This makes testing a lot easier.

Comment: So the class A should be declare as a bean by using Bean or Component annotation right? If not spring can not initiate a instance of MyClass using autowired?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `final` fields in the class, and generally even immutable class - less moving parts, cleaner code, easier to understand.

And the class is easier to test, you always know what properties to set in it to have a working class (because constructor forces you to set those) - of course one might still pass nulls in the params.

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing but `constructor based dependency injection`.

This link will have more info
[Constructor based dependency injection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowiring_byconstructor.htm)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to understand more on @Autowired

Spring explained it on it's documentation:

1. [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) on constructor autowired
2. [SpringFramework documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation) to explain how can used it on constructor, setter and property.

A litle resume can be, when spring create the bean is autowired when it found an annotation `@Autowired`